# Incorporating boolean data into analysis

Tags: modeling, categorical-data, model-selection, binary-data

I have a data set of about 3,000 field observations.

The data collected is divided into 20 variables (real numbers), 30 boolean variables, and 10 or so look up variables and one "answer" variable

We have about 20,000 objects in the field, and i'm trying to produce an "answer" for the 20,000 objects based on the 3,000 observations.

What are some of the available methods that incorporate booleans and look up tables?

any suggestions on how i should proceed?

**EDIT**

the answer variable is a boolean as well

**EDIT 2**

a sample of the variable data:

- Age of specimen
- length, area, volume
- time since last inspection
- height
- design life

Lookup table

- material type
- coating type
- design standard
- design effectiveness

a sample of the boolean

- is it inspected?
- is it in bad shape
- does it need repairs soon

the answer variable which is my f(x) is:

- is it useable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are decribing "[**categorical** variables](http://www.oswego.edu/~srp/stats/variable_types.htm)" (represented in R a factors). These can be incorporated into almost any statistical model by being assigned levels.  You would need to give more detail about your particular problem in order to be advised on a particular method.

*Edit*

If the response variable has two possible outcomes, you might consider [binomial](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_regression) or [logistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) regression.

Note: If you're not familiar with the different kinds of variables in statistics, I suggest reading the first few chapters of Andrew Gelman's "[Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/)" which covers this in a very understandable manner.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are trying to predict your boolean response, yes?

This is called classification.

Logistic Regression is the obvious choice here, but there are other methods too. You can't do traditional regression, because the response is not a real number.

The lookup variables are called nominals, and can be dealt with in regression by using "dummy" variables.

For example, if your lookup variable is type=[steel, aluminum, plastic] (N=3), then your dummy variables would look like this:

IsSteel = [1,0]
IsAlum = [1,0]

There would only be two (N-1) dummy variables, as IsSteel=0 AND IsAlum=0 represents "IsPlastic"=1

But any good stats program should handle this.

If you need a book, I recommend Multivariate Data Analysis by Hair.

Answer (score 4):

[Ingo Ruczinski](http://biostat.jhsph.edu/~iruczins/) has contributed to promote the use of [Logic regression](http://kooperberg.fhcrc.org/logic/documents/intro.html) for data set consisting of binary variables, with an emphasis on higher-order interaction terms. The main advantage compared to usual or penalized GLMs is that it is more parcimonious in terms of degrees of freedom. The outcome may be continuous or categorical, and continuous covariates can be added to the model (or the outcome can first be residualized on them if these are the binary predictors that are of interest).

The original paper

> Ruczinski I, Kooperberg C, LeBlanc ML
>   (2003). [Logic Regression](http://kooperberg.fhcrc.org/papers/2003logic.pdf).
>   *Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics*, 12(3), 475-511.

includes several applications in biomedical studies, and a comparison of LR with [CART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_and_regression_tree) and [MARS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_adaptive_regression_splines). Although it has mainly been applied in large-scale genetic studies (e.g. genome-wide association studies), it should work with any binary variables whose combinations of interest can be expressed with a set of logical operators.

The [LogicReg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LogicReg/index.html) R package implements this technique; see also the related packages on CRAN and Bioconductor, esp. [LogicForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LogicForest/index.html) which shares some ideas with Random Forests.

Answer (score 1):

Try Random Forest; from my experience it may perform well on such kind of data, and gives you a some additional interesting information, like variable importance and object similarity measure.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I must say that some explanation or reasoning why to use random forest could make this answer very much more interesting. ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but why random forest over SVM (for instance)?

Comment: I didn't downvote either, it didn't let me ;-) . @Peter extended. @Shane and why binomial regression? This is just my favorite algorithm and it may work well in this case.

Comment: +1 @mbq because to some extent, that's the "standard" and/or "obvious" answer when it comes to regression. :) (hope that's vague enough...) When it comes to a machine-learning approach, it doesn't seem to me that there is an obvious answer; but your experience is more than enough.